# Productflavors with different default language resource strings

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an app with two product flavors. One (INT) is available in German and English, the other one is only available in German (GER) but has some different strings in German than the first one.

My setup at the moment is:

INT has English in the default strings.xml and German in the values-de folder.
GER has both files filled with only the German strings that are different from INT (it's not enough to have them in the default folder, because on German devices, the -de strings of INT would be used).

The problem I have is, that when a device is set to another language than German the default strings of INT are used for strings that are not different in GER and thus not in its own default resource file. So I have a mix of German and English strings in the GER- App.
I hope you understand what I mean ;)

I understand why gradle behaves like that, but I hope there is a better solution than manually keeping all strings from the INT-App also in the GER-App's default strings...?

Telling resConfigs to only use German doesn't help. I would need something that tells gradle to always check German string-resources first for this flavor.
I saw suggestions of copying strings from one resource file to another in the build process, which might actually work for me, but it I will probably add more buildFlavors over time and I actually don't want to copy resource files for every build...

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Thanks a lot!
jpm

Comment: You should put strings files only inside the flavors foldes and not in the main shared folder

Answer (score 0):

In the German flavor, **do not put german strings in the `strings.xml` resource file**, but English ones.

This way, even if the user uses the german flavor of the app they will see the correct strings depending on their device language.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the problem is exactly the opposite. Users of the GER-App should never see English strings.

Comment: I understand. But why? If the user has set their language to English, they should see english translations - it should not matter whether they use the english or the german version. This makes it better for the user and easier for you.

Comment: It is not just a German version of the same App it is a complete different version of the app. That's why it also has different German texts. Its name is different its wording is different and there is no English translation for this version of the app. Believe me...there is a reason ;)

Comment: @jpm I understand that there might be business requirements behind this. However, I do not believe you can accomplish what you want, but by following my suggestion above it will be better for your users and an easy solution for you.